# Custom component: different redirect when changing language/logging in

Tags: sef, redirect, joomla-3.9, php7, router

I inherited a site with a custom component: an agenda viewer. When I click on an agenda-item from the list and then login (via login module) or change the language, I am not redirected to the agenda item but instead to the agenda list again.

How an I fix this so that I am being redirected to the agenda-item page again?

Logging out works perfectly however.

The base64 return value is also the correct url for the agendaitem page (for both login and logout).

Based on previous searches, I know that this has to do something with SEF. And when I disable SEF, the custom component page cannot be found (and I would like to keep SEF enabled). Also based on previous research, I think the issue must lie in `router.php`.
Here is that file:

```
<?php
// No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

/**
 * @param   array   A named array
 * @return  array
 */
function Protagoras_agendaBuildRoute(&$query)
{
    $segments = array();

    if (isset($query['task'])) {
        $segments[] = implode('/',explode('.',$query['task']));
        unset($query['task']);
    }
    if (isset($query['id'])) {
        $segments[] = $query['id'];
        unset($query['id']);
    }

    return $segments;
}

/**
 * @param   array   A named array
 * @param   array
 *
 * Formats:
 *
 * index.php?/protagoras_agenda/task/id/Itemid
 *
 * index.php?/protagoras_agenda/id/Itemid
 */
function Protagoras_agendaParseRoute($segments)
{

    $vars = array();

    /**
     * Agenda-item
     */
    if(!empty($segments[0])) {
        $id = explode( ':', $segments[0] );
        $vars['id']     = $id[0];
        $vars['view']   = 'agendaitem';

    } else {
        $vars['view'] = 'agendaitems';
    }

    return $vars;
}
?>
```

Edit: added http requests/responses

```
While not logged in:
Navigating to agenda:
https://www.protagoras.tue.nl/studenten/vereniging/agenda
Navigating to agenda item:
https://www.protagoras.tue.nl/studenten/vereniging/agenda/1760-woensdag-puzzeldag

Logging in while on agenda item page:
status 303 Post:
https://www.protagoras.tue.nl/studenten/vereniging/agenda
form data:
username=USERNAME
password=PASSWORD
option=com_users
task=user.login
return=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cucHJvdGFnb3Jhcy50dWUubmwvc3R1ZGVudGVuL3ZlcmVuaWdpbmcvYWdlbmRhLzE3NjAtd29lbnNkYWctcHV6emVsZGFn
85abb6f5daccba2a45c3c4ff59f8cfe7=1
Submit=""

status 200 Get:
https://www.protagoras.tue.nl/studenten/vereniging/agenda

Logging out while on agenda item:
status 303 Post:
https://www.protagoras.tue.nl/studenten/vereniging/agenda
form data:

option=com_users
task=user.logout
return=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cucHJvdGFnb3Jhcy50dWUubmwvc3R1ZGVudGVuL3ZlcmVuaWdpbmcvYWdlbmRhLzE3NjAtd29lbnNkYWctcHV6emVsZGFn
0714e4c8ac53d16d7ec8287fe4eedb9f=1

status 200 Get:
https://www.protagoras.tue.nl/studenten/vereniging/agenda/1760-woensdag-puzzeldag
```

Edit 2: added Post request locations

```
response header location Post request when logging in:
Location: /studenten/vereniging/agenda

response header location Post request when logging out:
Location: https://www.protagoras.tue.nl/studenten/vereniging/agenda/1760-woensdag-puzzeldag
```

SOLUTION: component did not contain associations (https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_Associations). Disabling plugins->languagefilter->associations did the trick but it would be best to write an associations functionality for this component. Thanks Robbie Jackson (see comments below)

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  While you wait for support, please take our [tour]. Also, a couple of non-resolving tips: 1. `implode('/',explode('.',$query['task']))` is better written as `str_replace('.', '/', $query['task'])` and 2. If `$segments[0]` will always have a colon, you can more directly use `strstr($segments[0], ':', true)` to get the id without generating a temporary array.

Comment: Could you put your browser devtools on, trace through the http requests/responses for going from the agendas page to the agenda page, then the effects of logging in and logging out. It would be helpful to have each URL, http request type (get/post) and parameters and response codes – could you add that information to your question? Also could you put the Joomla debug on and have a look in the debug session area when you're doing that navigation, and let us know if there's any differences there for your agenda component. Thanks

Comment: If you're changing the language via the Joomla language switcher module, then at the level you're talking about I think you'd need to have the agenda component supporting Joomla language associations, and have an association set up between the agenda item in one language and the corresponding agenda item in the other language. Plus you'd need the agenda component to use those associations via code in the agenda component's site helpers/association.php file. Is that all in place?

Comment: @RobbieJackson I added the request/reponses. But I am not sure what to add from the Joomla debug page? Also, the helpers/association.php file is not present, but I am more concerned about the login.

Comment: OK thanks. Where you've got the POST requests which have the 303 status response, in the response header you'll have the location of the URL which it's redirecting to. Could you add in that URL for those 303 responses? Also looking at the code for user login in components/com_users/controllers/user.php, it sets "the return URL in the user state to allow modification by plugins". Is there any plugin associated with the component (or more generally on your site) which might be modifying this return URL?

Comment: Also, when you navigate from the agendas page to the single agenda item, is it just a single HTTP GET or is there an HTTP POST involved at all?

Comment: @RobbieJackson there are no plugins associated with the component as far as I know, or the previous maintainer must have done some core hacks, but that seems highly unlikely. I also added the relevant rules from the .htaccess file

Comment: From agenda page to single item is only one single GET request

Comment: The issue does seem to be within the login method in components/com_users/controllers/user.php. The return parameter is right on entry, but the redirect URL doesn't match it on output. Could you edit this file and log the value of $data['return'] just before the comment "Set the return URL in the user state to allow modification by plugins" and then before the final redirect at the end of the method log the value of $app->getUserState('users.login.form.return'). (You can use https://docs.joomla.org/Using_JLog to log a message or enqueue a message if you don't mind users seeing it).

Comment: You could also do a search through files in the plugins directory for the string "users.login.form.return" and see if anything appears.

Comment: I just ran ```grep -r "users.login.form.return" *``` in the Joomla installation folder. Besides ```components/com_users/controllers/user.php```, ```plugins/system/languagefilter/languagefilter.php``` also matched (and no edits were made to this file by previous maintainers). After some experimentation I determined that disabling "Associations" in this plugin fixes the issue. But now users are redirected to the front page again if they switch language. Do you think that writing a ```helpers/association.php```  file allow me to enable Associations again?

Comment: Yes, that's the plugin that's changing the redirect URL, in the onUserLogin method, which will be run after the user logs on. If you get associations working on that component it will behave the way you want (including when you change language), but it may involve a bit of work. What you need to do to support associations in a component is described in https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_Associations. Adding the helper file is just part of it, and as I don't know how much of associations the component already supports I don't know how much extra work it would all be